# Dynamically selecting colors and themes in a page

Tags: php

I want to create a page by using **PHP** in such a way that page should contains a few color change options and themes by selecting those colors or themes it should reflect in the same page. Any suggestions or script for that?

Comment: can anyone pls give sugessions on this topic which i ve posted or scripts for dis..??

Comment: I don't really understand what it is that you want.  Can you rephrase the question a little more clearly, and give some html/css examples of the various themes that need to be changed?

Comment: k i think u ve used orkut there they ve provided a option for us to change the themes.. Same way i want a script so that the user can change the themes which they like. how to do that in Php.. I think now u understood clearly...

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not familiar with Orkut.

Comment: k if ur nt familair abt orkut leave that but i think ull be having ur email id there they ve given options of changing the themes which u like same way i ve to implement it in my page using php. can anyone help me in dis.

Comment: can anyone come up with the answers abt the topic which i ve posted..

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to get some sort of personalized theme for a php site is to use different stylesheets for different themes and store them into the users' browser [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp). Not the most ideal but works for most users.

Say you have 3 stylesheets named default.css, theme1.css and theme2.css.

default.css:

```
body {
  color: blue,
  background-color: white;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

theme1.css:

```
body {
  color: black,
  background-color: yellow;
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

Here's a sample code to output the link to different stylesheet depending on what was stored in the cookies else use a default one.

```
<head>
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['siteTheme']))
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/' . $_COOKIE["siteTheme"] . '" />";
else
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/default.css" />';
?>
<!-- other elements in head -->
</head>
```

To store the user selected theme, you might have a dropdown or hyperlinks to a page which will then set the cookies.

Say a hyperlink to "`setTheme.php?theme=theme1`", "`theme=theme2`" etc.

Or a dropdown form

```
<form method='get' action='/setTheme.php'>
<select name='theme' onchange='this.form.submit();'>
<option value='default'>default</option>
<option value='theme1'>Theme 1</option>
<option value='theme2'>Theme 2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In the setTheme.php page, add the following:

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30; //exipiry of the cookie
setcookie("siteTheme", $_GET["theme"], $expire); //store the selected theme to cookie
?>
```

Then have a link back to the home page with the theme stylesheet selection code (the first one right above) in place, and you are done.

PS: Will not work for browsers not support cookies or cookie disabled.

*Disclaimer: I've not tested the actual codes above, but conceptually it should work.*